# (Swift SpriteKit) Only allow SKScene to present once

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This code resides in the viewDidLoad function. The first time it is called it is fine. But then I present a subView on top of it from the same storyboard file and when 'let skView = gameView as! SKView' gets called again and throws a Fatal error: Found nil... How do I stop it from being called the other times? I can't think of any checks I could but in place.

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.

        let skView = gameView as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        if skView.scene == nil {
            if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
}
```